# Referencing field from joined type in update

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hql

I have a problem with inheritance:

A class Item and a class User witch extends from Item

```
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Entity
@Table(name = "item")
public class Item{
    ...
    Date lastdate;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User extends Item{
    ...
    Date logindate
}
```

And I want to do this query:

```
update User u set u.lastdate=u.logindate where u.id = ?1
```

But it throw an exception: `Unknown column 'logindate' in 'field list'`, because it tries to execute this:

```
update item set lastdate=logindate where (item_id) IN (select item_id from HT_user)
```

How can I reference the item.lastdate and the user.logindate in my HQL Update query?

Comment: how your table item, and user looks like? Are they creates by hibernate ?